# how to solve this using Pigeonhole principle

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, pigeonhole-principle

We need to arrange the following numbers in a circular shape `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)` with the following conditions:

for each one we should prove that it's impossible according to the [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

**i)** The sum of three numbers next to each other is no less than 17

**ii)** The sum of three numbers next to each other is no less than 18

**iii)** The sum of three numbers next to each other is no less than 19

I tried to solve this using beads, I said that we have 55 beads (the sum of all numbers), at first we need to put one beed on every chair around the table since 0 is not allowed then we are left with 45 beads, one chair will have 10 beads for sure so we need to add to a random chair 9 more beads so we are left with 36 beads.

But I can't continue from here...

Comment: There are $10$ triples of consecutive numbers, however they are arranged.  If you sum all the triples then you get $3\times 55=165$ since each digit is counted exactly three times.   But if each triple is at least $17$ the triples sum to at least $170$.

Comment: This is for number 2, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3581750/751970

Comment: @lulu It's not "all triples sum to at least 17". It's "is it possible that all triples sum to at most 17 (or 18, depending on how you view it)".

Comment: Construct an example where the triple sum is at most 18. From the linked problem, you know that one of the triples must be at least 18.

Comment: @CalvinLin  The post clearly says "no less than" not "at most".  Indeed, it's obvious that there could be a triple that sums over $19$...we could have $8,9,10$ in sequence, for instance.

Comment: It's "We need to prove if it is impossible to arrange the following numbers subject to "the sum of three numbers next to each other is no less than 17". We can to choose the construction. As it turns out, there will always be a triple that sum to at least 17 or 18, but there **need not** be a triple that sums to 19.

Comment: for number 3, is $1,10,6,2,8,7,3,5,9,4$ a counter example?

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja You are right, could you kindly explain how did you get that solution? was it random? cause I tried a lot and didn't work for me

Comment: If you look at the solution to 2, you'd realize that when $a_1=1$, we must have $a_2+a_3+a_4=a_5+a_6+a_7=a_8+a_9+a_{10} = 18$, which greatly restricts what we should try. Another sequence (with a similar start) is $1, 10, 6, 2, 9, 5, 4, 8, 3, 7$.

Comment: @clark_smith based on solution of number 2 in my previous comment, I try to divide $2,3,...,10$ into 3 distinct triplets, each sum to $18$. I did this like filling $3\times 3$ magic square. Other than that, just luck

Comment: So since we have proven ii we can easily prove i. am I correct?